# php ajax based form displaying blank page

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have created a eBay Item search form. I want to make form.html to form.php but when I change it to .php the form doesn't work and display blank page. you can see form.html here:

```
<script>
        function showDetail(name){
            $("."+name).collapse('toggle');
        }
        function getPage(num){
                var data = {
                    "action": "test",
                    "pageNumber": num
                };
                data = $('form').serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

            // jQuery AJAX call to PHP Script with JSON Return      
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "advancedItemSearchTest.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
            data: data,
            success: function(new_data) {

            $( ".container" ).hide();
            $( ".the-return" ).html( "" );// clear all the contents first
            if(new_data['ack'] != 'Success' || new_data['resultCount'] <= 0){
                $( ".the-return" ).html( "<h2>No Results were found</h2>" );
            }
            else{
                for ( var i = 0; i < new_data.itemCount; i++ ) {
                    var $media = $( '<div class = "media"></div>');
                    var $media_body = $( '<div class = "media-body"></div>');
                    var $a_class = $('<a class= "pull-left"></a>');
                    var $name = 'name' + i;
                    //<img class = "media-object" src =  alt = "Item Image" />
                    //<a href= "<?php echo $item->viewItemURL ?>"><?php echo $item->title ?></a>

                    var $item = new_data['item'][i];
                    var $imageURL = $item['basicInfo']['galleryURL'];
                    var $price = $item['basicInfo']['convertedCurrentPrice']
                    var $title = '<a href = '+ $item['basicInfo']['viewItemURL']+ '>' + $item['basicInfo']['title'] + '</a>';

                    var $image = '<img class = "media-object" src =' + $imageURL +'alt = "Item Image" style="width:96px;height:96px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal'+ $name +'"/>';// concatenating string must use+ for variable!!
                    var $modal = $('<div class="modal fade" id="myModal'+ $name +'" role="dialog"></div>');
                    var $modalDialog = $('<div class="modal-dialog"></div>');
                    var $modalContent = $('<div class="modal-content"></div>');
                    $modalContent.append($('<div class="modal-header"></div>').append('<h4 class="modal-title">'+$item['basicInfo']['title']+'</h4>'));
                    $modalContent.append($('<div class="modal-body"></div>').append('<img src='+$item['basicInfo']['pictureURLSuperSize']+' alt="Item image" style="width:512px;height:512px" align="middle">'));
                    $modalContent.append($('<div class="modal-footer"></div>').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'));
                    $modalDialog.append($modalContent);
                    $modal.append($modalDialog);

                    var $shippingCost = "(Free Shipping)";
                    if($item['basicInfo']['shippingServiceCost'] > 0){
                        $shippingCost = "(+$" + $item['basicInfo']['shippingServiceCost'] + ")";
                    }
                    $price = "<b>" + "Price:$" + $price + "</b>";
                    var $location = "<i>" + "Location:"+ $item['basicInfo']['location'] + "</i>";
                    var $topRated = "";
                    if($item['basicInfo']['topRatedListing']){
                        $topRated = '<img  src =' + 'http://cs-server.usc.edu:45678/hw/hw8/itemTopRated.jpg' +' alt = "Top Rated" style="width:32px;height:24px" />';
                    }

                    var $collapse = $('<div class="collapse '+ $name +'"></div>');// 
                    var $ul = $('<ul class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>');
                    $ul.append($('<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#basic'+ $name +'">Basic Info</a></li>'));
                    $ul.append($('<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#seller'+ $name +'">Seller Info</a></li>'));
                    $ul.append($('<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#shipping'+ $name +'">Shipping Info</a></li>'));
                    $collapse.append($ul);
                    var $tabContend = $('<div class="tab-content"></div>');

                    var $basic = $('<div id="basic'+ $name +'" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>');

                    var $table = $('<tbody></tbody>');//$('<table class = "table table-striped" ></table>');
                    var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Condition</b></td>' + '<td>'+$item['basicInfo']['conditionDisplayName']+'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Category Name</b></td>' + '<td>'+$item['basicInfo']['categoryName']+'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tabContend.append($basic.append($('<table class = "table table-striped" ></table>').append($table)));

                    var $seller = $('<div id="seller'+ $name +'" class="tab-pane fade"></div>');
                    $table = $('<tbody></tbody>');//$('<table class = "table table-striped""></table>');
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    $tr.append('<td><b>User name</b></td>' + '<td>'+$item['sellerInfo']['sellerUserName']+'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Feedback score</b></td>' + '<td>'+$item['sellerInfo']['feedbackScore']+'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Positive feedback</b></td>' + '<td>'+$item['sellerInfo']['positiveFeedbackPercent']+'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    var $storeName = 'N/A';
                    if($item['sellerInfo']['sellerStoreName']!=''){
                        $storeName = $item['sellerInfo']['sellerStoreName'];
                    }
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Store name</b></td>' + '<td>'+$storeName+'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tabContend.append($seller.append($('<table class = "table table-striped" ></table>').append($table)));

                    var $shipping = $('<div id="shipping'+ $name +'" class="tab-pane fade"></div>');

                    $table = $('<tbody></tbody>');//$('<table class = "table table-striped""></table>');
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Shipping type</b></td>' + '<td>'+$item['shippingInfo']['shippingType']+'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Handling time</b></td>' + '<td>'+$item['shippingInfo']['handlingTime']+'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Shipping locations</b></td>' + '<td>'+$item['shippingInfo']['shipToLocations']+'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    //&#10004(correct)  &#10008(wrong)
                    var $mark = "&#10008";
                    if($item['shippingInfo']['expeditedShipping']){
                        $mark = "&#10004";
                    }
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Expedited shipping</b></td>' + '<td>'+ $mark +'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    //&#10004(correct)  &#10008(wrong)
                    var $mark = "&#10008";
                    if($item['shippingInfo']['returnsAccepted']){
                        $mark = "&#10004";
                    }
                    $tr.append('<td><b>Return accepted</b></td>' + '<td>'+ $mark +'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    //&#10004(correct)  &#10008(wrong)
                    var $mark = "&#10008";
                    if($item['shippingInfo']['oneDayShippingAvailable']){
                        $mark = "&#10004";
                    }
                    $tr.append('<td><b>One day shipping</b></td>' + '<td>'+ $mark +'</td>');
                    $table.append($tr);
                    $tabContend.append($shipping.append($('<table class = "table table-striped" ></table>').append($table)));

                    $collapse.append($tabContend);                  

                    var $viewDetail= '<a onclick="showDetail(\'' + $name +'\')">View Detail</a>';//'+$name+'
                    $media.append($a_class.html( $image));
                    $media_body.append($collapse);
                    $media_body.prepend( '<font size="4">' + $title + '</font>' + '<br/>' + $price + $shippingCost + ' ' + $location  + ' ' +  $topRated  + ' ' + $viewDetail );

                    $media.append($media_body);

                    $media.appendTo( $( ".the-return" ) );
                    $modal.appendTo( $( ".the-return" ) );

                }
                var $pagination = $('<div class = "pagination"></div>');
                var $ul = $('<ul class="pagination"></ul>');
                var $prev = num - 1;
                if( num == 1){
                    $pagination.append($ul.append('<li class="disabled"><a href="#">' + '<<' + '</a></li>'));
                }
                else{
                    $pagination.append($ul.append('<li><a href="#' + $prev +'" onclick="getPage(' + $prev + ');">' + '<<' + '</a></li>'));
                }

                for( var i = num; i < num+5; i++ ){
                    $pagination.append($ul.append('<li><a href="#' + i +'" onclick="getPage(' + i + ');">' + i + '</a></li>'));

                }
                var $next = num + 1;
                if( num == new_data['totalPages']){
                    $pagination.append($ul.append('<li class="disabled"><a href="#">' + '>>' + '</a></li>'));
                }
                else{
                    $pagination.append($ul.append('<li><a href="#' + $next +'" onclick="getPage(' + $next + ');">' + '>>' + '</a></li>'));
                }
                var $itemFrom = (num-1) * Number(new_data.itemCount) + 1;
                var $itemTo = $itemFrom +  Number(new_data.itemCount) - 1;
                var $resultNum = $( '<div class = "resultNum" ></div>').append( '<b><font size="5">'+$itemFrom +'-'+ $itemTo + ' items out of ' + new_data['resultCount'] +'</font></b>');
                $resultNum.prependTo($( ".the-return" ));
                $pagination.appendTo( $( ".the-return" ) );
            }   
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                //alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            keyword: {      // should be name, not id!
                required: true
            },
            priceLow: {
                number: true,
                digits: true
            },
            priceHigh: {
                number: true,
                digits: true        
            },
            shippingTime:{
                number: true,
                digits: true
            }

        },
        messages:{
            keyword: {      // should be name, not id!
                required: "Please enter a keyword"
            },
            priceLow: {
                number: "Price should be a valid number",
                digits: "Price should be a valid number",
                min : "Minimum price cannot be below 0"         
            },
            priceHigh: {
                number: "Price should be a valid number",
                digits: "Price should be a valid number",
                min : "Maximum price cannot be less than minimum price or below 0"              
            },
            shippingTime:{
                number:  "Max handling time should be a valid digit",
                digits:  "Max handling time should be a valid digit",
                min: "Max handling time should be greater than or equal to 1"
            }

        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });


    $('form').submit(function(){
        //var num = 1;

        getPage(1);
        return false;
    });
}); // end document.ready


</script>

</head>

<body>
<style>
.center_div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:80%;
}
</style>

<div class = "container center_div" >
    <img src = " http://cs-server.usc.edu:45678/hw/hw8/ebay.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br>
    <form class = "form-horizontal" action = "advancedItemSearchTest.php" method="GET" role = "form" id = "myForm" accept-charset="utf-8">  
            <div class = "form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="keyword">Key words:*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type = "text" class="form-control" id = "keyword" name = "keyword" placeholder="Enter keyword">
                </div>

                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="keyword">APP ID</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type = "text" class="form-control" id = "appid" name = "appid" placeholder="Enter appID">
                </div>

            </div>  
            <div class = "form-group row">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="priceLow">Price range:  </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type = "number" class="form-control" name = "priceLow" id = "priceLow" min="0" placeholder="from($)">
                    </div>
                    <label class="control-label " for="priceHigh">  </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type = "number" class="form-control" name = "priceHigh" id = "priceHigh" min="0" placeholder="to($)"> 
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="conditionNew">Condition:  </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id = "conditionNew" name = "condition[]" value=1000>New</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "condition[]" value=3000>Used</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "condition[]" value=4000>Very Good</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "condition[]" value=3000>Good</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "condition[]" value=4000>Acceptable</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="formats">Buying formats:  </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id = "formats" name = "BuyFormat[]" value="FixedPrice">Buy It Now</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "BuyFormat[]" value="Auction">Auction</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "BuyFormat[]" value="Classified">Classified Ad</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="shipping">Shipping:  </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id = "shipping" name = "FreeShippingOnly" value="true">Free Shipping</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "ExpeditedShippingType" value="Expedited">Expedited shipping</label>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="shippingTime">  </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type = "number" class="form-control" name = "shippingTime" id = "shippingTime" min="1"  placeholder="Max handling time(days)"> 
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-10"   align="right">          
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Clear" >
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
            </div>
    </form>
```

when form is in .html extension it works fine but when I change it to .php it display blank page.

Comment: please check it now

Comment: yes. sorry that was typed mistakenly it is fine in .html but not working in .php

Comment: Please add PHP error handling to your server and try again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Answer (score 1):

Change the last button type from submit to button.

In submit It will redirect on new page.

Comment: I changed the submit to button like this <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button> and its working.. can you tell me why?

Comment: When we use submit button then It will submit the form according to the action. For simple call a JS function on a button we just need to use button.